# Fingerprint authentication problem after updated to iOS 13

Tags: swift, xcode, fingerprint, ios13

I have an app need the fingerprint authentication when every time the app started, so that i have put the fingerprint authentication into applicationDidBecomeActive in AppDelegate.

After my iPad and Xcode updated to iOS 13, the fingerprint dialog popup delayed around 30 seconds to 1 min. (It is popup immediately before updated to iOS 13)

Has anyone had a similar situation?

```
if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error){
    let reason = "Fingerprint Login"

    context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason ) { success, error in

    if success {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            print("Success")
        }                    
    } else {  
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to authenticate")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, any solution?

Comment: not yet, please let me know if you have solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read that this is a common bug in iOS 13, i think they will fix it in the upcoming versions, for now just call `context.evaluatePolicy` twice like that :

```
if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error){
    let reason = "Fingerprint Login"

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason ) { (_,_) in }
    }
    context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason ) { success, error in
        if success {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
                print("Success")
            }
        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to authenticate")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, it is totally work, i think your solution can use for temporary until they fixed the bug, thanks for your help ~~